# How to remove this weird label on an IntelliJ IDEA Maven module?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I accidentally created some kind of label, or at least it looks like some kind of label, on a Maven module in an IntelliJ IDEA project. It looks like this (followed by the module name):

[image: Weird Label]

I don't remember exactly how the text got there. I think the module was selected and that I accidentally pressed some key combination, followed by "7". It was really just a keyboard slip.

The annoying thing is, it is stuck there. I have restarted IntelliJ, but it won't disappear.

Is this some kind of feature or is it a weird display bug? In either case, how do I get rid of it?

I am running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 15.0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set a bookmark.

Highlight it and press `ctrl + shift + 7` to clear.

Or `shift + f11` to list all bookmarks.